# Como converter object em numero no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

arq = pd.read_csv("arquivo.csv", sep=";")
```

Quero usar valores na coluna de `Valor` mas está em `object`. Porém, quando uso o código `arq["Valor"] = arq["Valor"].astype(int)` aparece o erro:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '54.00'

Comment: arq["Valor"] = arq["Valor"].astype(int) aparece o erro: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '54.00'  Mas quando troco: arq["Valor"] = arq["Valor"].astype(float) aparece o seguinte erro: could not convert string to float: ' 14.170.00'

Answer (score 0):

O que o erro está te dizendo é que o Python tentou converter a string "54.00" para int, e não conseguiu, mesmo as duas casas depois do ponto sendo zero. Você pode converter a coluna valor usando astype(float) que vai transformar os valores na coluna "Valor" em um inteiro com casas decimais.